# What is the problem with Websocket and Self-Signed SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket, ssl-certificate

I have a project runs on intranet, so I didn't buy any SSL certificate or domain name. Instead, I created self-signed certificate. I have two layer one of which is web service/websocket and the other is view. Everything is OK for all https connections, hence all pages, but browser could not make connection with ws or wss links(was tried ports 8443,443,8080). If I write link with localhost instead of my ip, it works perfectly, but then I cannot use it from another device. I created certificete as RSA/2048. My project runs on Ubuntu 18.04. Serverside was written in Java-Spring Boot.

Comment: what is the error shown in the browser console?

Comment: Firefox can not establish connection with this URL. Maybe translation is not true, because my browser is in my language, error is too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If someone else need an answer, I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985201/11640370). As summary, the problem is about Firefox, not about other browsers. Main reason is that Firefox do not accept certificate of wss link, in fact it is also the same certificate for the first connection link start with https. Solution is to go to the link started with wss by chancing wss to https and accept privilege of that link, and everthing works fine :)